# How to fix Facebook Open Graph tags in new WordPress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am building a WordPress site behind the scenes while I have a "Coming Soon" page showing on the front end. I wanted to share the site with someone to show the landing page, and this showed up as the thumbnail:

[image: Website Thumbnail]

This is obviously not what I want.

I went to developers.facebook.com and checked out the Open Graph properties. The following are the og:title, og:description, and og:markup_url:

**og:title**

```
    Web hosting provider - Bluehost.com - domain hosting - PHP Hosting - cheap web hosting - Frontpage Hosting E-Commerce Web Hosting Bluehost
```

**og:description**

```
    Bluehost - Top rated web hosting provider - Free 1 click installs For blogs, shopping carts, and more. Get a free domain name, real NON-outsourced 24/7 support, and superior speed. web hosting provider php hosting cheap web hosting, Web hosting, domain names, front page hosting, email hosting. We of...
```

**og:markup_url (shortened for the sake of brevity)**

```
    <meta name="description" content="Bluehost - Top rated web hosting provider - Free 1 click installs ... />

    <meta name="keywords" content="web hosting, provider, php hosting,web hosting,.../>

    <meta name="revisit-after" content="10" />

    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
```

I tried to edit the functions.php file of the default theme that is being used currently, which is the 2016 theme per suggestions on WordPress forums, but my theme isn't what's being shown, and it didn't work.

I also tried to add a plugin specifically for Facebook, Twitter, Google+ Open Graph tags, but that didn't work either.

What file is being picked up by the crawlers that displays this information? I can't seem to find these meta tags.

Comment: Looks like your web hoster injects this, no? Did you maybe use a "Coming Soon" feature (or something like that) from your hoster’s panel?

Comment: @unor No I used a plugin from the WordPress backend.

Comment: #1 - your "coming soon" does not appear to be **a WordPress page**, but rather you're still using Bluehost's placeholder page.  CHANGE THAT immediately.  #2 - If you install [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin, it takes care of these things for you.

Comment: @cale_b The placeholder page part is new to me. I'm gonna do some research on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was easier than I thought. I noticed the last URL scrape was November 11, 2016. I clicked "Scrape Again" on the Facebook Sharing Debugger page, and the correct link came up.

So, it was a simple cache issue.

Thank you for the suggestions, friends!

[image: Correct Share Link]